# How to monitor systemd timers and path-invoked systemd processes

Tags: systemd, monitoring, snmp

We used to use cron and switched to systemd timers for a number of scheduled tasks on our machines.  With cron, the solution wasn't perfect, but when things broke, we sent emails to a mailing list and when it got bad enough, we had to do something to stop the bleeding.

With systemd, everything just seems to fail silently.  We've got a snmp based monitoring solution, but it has no built in support for monitoring systemd timers.  What I'd like to know is, what solutions are there for an off-box Linux monitoring appliance to monitor the status of systemd timers?